# How can I load a local image from Keras?

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to load a local image in Keras but it is not working, I get a error when trying to display it:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py:364: FormatterWarning: image/png formatter returned invalid type <class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'> (expected (<class 'bytes'>, <class 'str'>)) for object: <IPython.core.display.Image object>
  FormatterWarning
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
```

I am using this notebook created by the founder of Keras(which works on it's own but it downloads a image from the internet):
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1H-lNMxVF9NPME6oZVphFRoi7yglJMZxP

I wanted to try to use my own images to play with style transfers, so I changed this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.applications import vgg19

# base_image_path = keras.utils.get_file('my_pic.jpg', './my_pic.png')
base_image_path = keras.utils.load_img('/content/my_pic.jpg')
style_reference_image_path = keras.utils.get_file('starry_night.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/9ooB60I.jpg')
result_prefix = 'paris_generated'
iterations = 5000

# Weights of the different loss components
total_variation_weight = 1e-6
style_weight = 2e-6
content_weight = 2e-8

# Dimensions of the generated picture.
width, height = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(base_image_path).size
img_nrows = 400
img_ncols = int(width * img_nrows / height)
```

When I make this change:

```
# base_image_path = keras.utils.get_file('my_pic.jpg', './my_pic.png')
base_image_path = keras.utils.load_img('/content/my_pic.jpg')
```

All the code stops working. I think the get_file approach is doing something to make it accessible as a picture because in the original notebook it displays the picture but for mine it doesn't not.

Is there any I can do to make this work? I'm brand new to working with images but I did research this and I think the get_file method is for getting files over the network so I think it will not work if I copy a file on my local colab system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would read a lot of tensorflow's documentation. It's actually amazing for most functions and things you want to do. For example [get_file](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/get_file) you can see it says Returns `Path to the downloaded file`. Whereas load_img will use a path to load the file into a PIL image object.

In the example what they're doing is downloading that file from the internet and get_file returns the path to that downloaded file, and then they use `keras.preprocessing.image.load_img` to load the image and get the dimensions (i.e width, height)

So to fix your problem. It's easy. Don't call the `keras.utils.load_img('/content/my_pic.jpg')`. All you need to do is set

```py
base_image_path = '/content/mypic.jpg'
```

Just remember this file path means you have a folder in the root of your drive called content. If you meant to put a relative path, then remove that first `/`.

**For example** If in colab/your lab there is a folder called content that's next to your notebook, then you want to use the relative path `content/mypic.jpg`. However if the image is located in your downloads then do something like this as an absolute path (ie C:\Users\USER\Downloads or /Users/USER/Downloads)

Comment: Thank you it worked. I didn't realize it just a path to a image. I thought it was doing some other processing behind the scenes. Thank you!

Comment: No worries. I hope it all works out for you. It's a fun tutorial